# Cisco Asa 5505 RDP problem with VPN connection

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa

I have a problem with my Cisco Asa 5505. My computer is connected to a Cisco ASA 5505 and I connect to via VPN to another Cisco ASA 5505.Everything works fine, but I can not use RDP to computers in the second network. It seems that my Cisco will stop outgoing traffic on port 3389. When I try to connect from another place with the same VPN connection, it works. So the problem must lie in my Cisco. Do I need to add an ACL for port 3389?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ASA/PIX devices have an explicit ACL policy, so whatever is not allowed explicitly, is denied

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. But I have tried to add an ACL, but it does not seem to work. No one who has an example of how to add it?